# for loops for creating dummy variable

Tags: r, database, variables, dummy-variable

I am currently working on online database called national inpatient sample using R studio.  I have procedure code called I10_PR1 to PR25. Then I have another called PRD1 to PRD 9 which tells the specific day the specific procedure is being performed. Day 0 is the day of admission and day 1 the next day and so on. I want to create a dummy variable first based on if the procedure is performed which I will write as below:

```
mydata$procedure = apply(new, 1, function(row){
  ifelse("procedure code " %in% row, 1, 0)
})
```

but I am having trouble in creating the time to that specific procedure. Could someone help with the correct code for that ?
Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I would suggest you to use package `fastDummies` for converting categorical variables to dummy variables.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. if you include example rows from this dataset, and an illustration of which kind of output you want, it will be more clear, and more likely to get useful answers.